# How to graph and solve this equation?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'am trying to solve this equation.

\begin{equation}
x^{8}+(x+2)^{8}=2
\end{equation}

What I tried:

\begin{equation}g(x)=x^{8}+(x+2)^{8}\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l}
\text {  }\\
y=x+1
\end{array}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
(y+1)^{8}+(y-1)^{8}=2
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
(y+1)^{8}=y^{8}+a_{7} y^{7}+a_{6} y^{6}+\cdots+a_{1} y+1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
(y-1)^{8}=y^{8}-a_{7} y^{7}+a_{6} y^{6}+\cdots-a_{1} y+1
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l}
2\left(y^{8}+a_{6} y^{6}+a_{4} y^{4}+a_{2} y^{2}+1\right)=2 \Leftrightarrow \\
y^{8}+a_{6} y^{6}+a_{4} y^{4}+a_{2} y^{2}=0 \Leftrightarrow y^{2}=0 \Leftrightarrow y=0
\end{array}
\end{equation}

y=0, x= -1

Maybe there is another way of solving this...

Comment: Okay, I will show. I understand that.

Comment: No, I don’t. I’am just starting to learn calculus.

Comment: I like your solution.  Very nice!

Comment: Since your polynomial is eigth degree, there are six more solutions (over the complex numbers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encourage you to keep working on your solution using derivatives. However, solving this equation does not need derivatives. Here I write a hint and if you need more help I'll give you another one!

Hint1:

> Rearrange the equation: $(x+2)^8 - 1 = 1 - x^8$

Edit: Ah! Now that you posted your work I see you don't need help. That is a good solution. Well done!

Now, here is an alternative solution. Not as nice and concise as yours, but still might be a good exercise. Like you, I too felt more comfortable with the variable change $y = x + 1$ . In fact this would be the hint number two! We have:
$$(y+1)^8 - 1^8 = 1^8 - (y-1)^8$$
$$[(y+1)^4+1][(y+1)^2+1](y+2)y = [1+(y-1)^4][1+(y-1)^2]y(2-y)$$
Clearly, one answer is $y=0$, which means $x=-1$ .

Below, we show that the equation does not have any other real answers. Assuming that $y \ne 0$ we can divide both sides by $y$ :
$$[(y+1)^4+1][(y+1)^2+1](y+2) = [1+(y-1)^4][1+(y-1)^2](2-y)$$
Without any more factorisation, we can find several useful things in the above equation:

Firstly, we can see that if $y>2$ or $y<-2$ then the two sides of the equation have different signs. Therefore the equation does not have any solutions in those value ranges.

Secondly, at $y=2$ and at $y=-2$ one side of the equation becomes zero while the other side is nonzero. So these two are not solutions of the equation either.

Finally, for $-2 < y < 2$ where both sides are positive, we can see that if $y > 0$ then each term of the left hand side is greater than its corresponding term in the right hand side (therefore left hand side $ > $ right hand side); and if $y < 0$ then each term of the left hand side is less than its corresponding term in the right hand side (therefore left hand side $ < $ right hand side). Either way, the two sides cannot be equal.

So we are left with the only case that $y=0$.

Comment: This is nice too (along with OP's solution)
!  What's next, expressing each side as a product using the "difference of two squares"?

Comment: Yes. Now that the user has solved the problem, I will add the rest, as an alternative solution.

Comment: But, how could I solve this with derivatives?

Comment: @Saeed, How does differentiating an equation give solutions?  $f(x)=0$ has solutions where $f=0$.  $f'(x)$ does not necessarily have the same zeros.

Comment: @mjw Please see Bendit's answer.

Comment: @mjw Sorry, you are right. That comment was inaccurately worded and misleading. I will remove it and refer OP to Theo's solution.

Comment: @Saeed, no problem.  Please see my comment there.

Comment: @user910220 I just deleted a misleading comment. If you have already read it, please disregard it. Theo's answer uses derivatives correctly: it comes up with an equation for a minimum point, verifies that this minimum point happens to satisfy the equation as well, and uses analysis to argue that it is the only real solution.

Answer (score 3):

OK then, let's use calculus.

Consider the function $f(x) = x^8 + (2 + x)^8$. Note that $f(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \pm \infty$, so the function must achieve a global minimum at a stationary point, i.e. where $f'(x) = 0$.

We have,
$$f'(x) = 8x^7 + 8(x + 2)^7.$$
This is $0$ if and only if
$$8x^7 + 8(x + 2)^7 = 0 \iff (x + 2)^7 = -x^7 \iff \left(\frac{x + 2}{x}\right)^7 = -1.$$
Note, for the above to work, we must observe that $x = 0$ is definitely not a solution. As we are considering only the reals, we can take the unique seventh root of both sides to obtain
$$\frac{x + 2}{x} = -1 \iff x + 2 = -x \iff x = -1.$$
That is, there exists one and only one stationary point for the whole function: at $x = -1$. Therefore, the global minimum of $f$ must be achieved only at this point. That is,
$$2 = f(-1) \le f(x)$$
for all $x \in \Bbb{R}$, with equality if and only if $x = -1$. This implies $f(x) = 2$ if and only if $x = -1$.

Comment: Turns out, by accident, or by design, that the (real) solution to the original equation $f(x)=0$ is also a solution to $f^\prime(x)=0$.  This is not always the case.  For example, consider the equation $x^3 = 1$, with $g(x)=x^3-1.$  The real solution is $x=1$, but surely $g^\prime(1) \ne 0.$

Comment: Indeed, @mjw makes an excellent point: this is an ad-hoc method tailored to this problem, not a general method for solving polynomial equations. Indeed, solving 8-degree polynomial equations exactly tends to be a matter of ad-hoc methods, or no method at all.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try
$$ 1 + 1 = 2.$$

$$ \left\{ 
\begin{aligned}
x^8=1\\
(x+2)^8=1 
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

A solution is $x=-1.$

---

Actually, $x=-1$ is a double root:

Let $q(x) = x^8 + (x+2)^8 -2$. So we have $$q(x)=0.$$  We can factor q(x):

$$q(x) = 2 (x+1)^2 (127 + 258 x + 253 x^2 + 132 x^3 + 43 x^4 + 6 x^5 + x^6).$$

The equation $127 + 258 x + 253 x^2 + 132 x^3 + 43 x^4 + 6 x^5 + x^6=0$
has no real solutions.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x)=x^8+(x+2)^8\qquad f'(x)=8x^7+8(x+2)^7\qquad f''(x)=56x^6+56(x+2)^6$$

$f''(x)$is clearly positive so $f$ is convex and above its tangents, in particular since $f'(-1)=0$ it is above the horizontal line $y=f(-1)+(x-1)f'(-1)=2$.

Since this value is effectively reached for $x=-1$ then it is the global minimum (no other because of convexity), and you can generalize to any $2n$ exponent instead of $8$.